# Scroll down div animation in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How to animate the each box when scrolling down the box will be animate like fade-in,
if scroll to the .box pageYOffset 20 that box will be fade-in, I tried with AOS third-party library and its worked fine but i want to know how to do scroll down animation without any third-party library

[myCode](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7caf8m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```js
@HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  onWindowScroll(e) {
    const box = document.querySelector('.box');
    if (window.pageYOffset < box.clientHeight ) {
      box.classList.add('colorChange');
    } else {
      box.classList.remove('colorChange');
    }
  }
```

```css
.container{
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding-top: 768px;
}
.box{
  background: #007aff;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  word-spacing: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin: 30px auto;
}
.colorChange{
  background: #fcad2e;
  animation: fade-in 1s ease-in-out;
}
@keyframes fade-in {
  from{
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(50px);
  }
  to{
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use intersection Oberserver for this if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works by specifically adding a window scroll event listener.

```
import { Component, VERSION, HostListener } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;
  constructor(){
    window.addEventListener("scroll", (event)=>{
    debugger;
    const box = document.querySelector('.box');
    if (window.pageYOffset < box.clientHeight ) {
      box.classList.add('colorChange');
    } else {
      box.classList.remove('colorChange');
    }
  });
  }
  }
```

[Here's link to working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-axceh4)

Comment: Thnaks John its working. But if i have multiple cards each card class name i given colorChange, How to animate each card with same class name

Comment: I am trying scroll down page animation